# Updating records in MS Access linked table will activate triggers?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, ms-access, dblink

I have a simple yet undocumented (or I could not find the documentation to solve my uneasiness) question, I hope I have come to the right place:

I am using MS Access to act as a <strike>poor</strike> front end for SQL Server. In this Access file I have some linked tables that will undergo some editing at various points by some users, be it via forms or directly accessing the table in spreadsheet view (I advised against this but, well...).

My concern is: the server has some procedures set on this table that are coded to **trigger** on insert/update. Will they be triggered when doing these edits via Access front end?

Comment: Yes, they will; the triggers shouldn't be aware of what causes the inserts/updates (except, maybe, for *restore* operations). Triggers care only about inserts/updates happening. And most probably, that's exactly what you actually want to happen.

Comment: That's great news. Thanks @joanolo . I assume this should be the default behaviour for every DB Management System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The Access frontend will not suppress the SQL procedures.